# O item ViewData que possui a chave 'Name' é do tipo 'System.String', mas precisa ser do tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'

Tags: c#, asp.net, mvc, asp.net-identity

Fala galera, sou novo na área de ASP.NET e estudando o Identity me deparei com um erro de tipagem ao realizar um registro de um novo usuário. O projeto foi feito com a própria autenticidade do VS.
Fiz a parte das Roles, que estão funcionando muito bem, o problema é quando registra um novo usuário com a role já cadastrada.

O erro é gerado na linha @Html.DropDownList("Name") da View Register ao tentar cadastrar o novo usuário.

O item ViewData que possui a chave 'Name' é do tipo 'System.String', mas precisa ser do tipo 'IEnumerable'.

Meu RegisterViewModel que fica dentro do AccountViewModel:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O/A {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Senha")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar Senha")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a senha de confirmação não correspondem.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Meu Controller (GET e POST) que fica dentro do AccountController:

```
    // GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
        return View();
    }

    //
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                //Atribui o Peril ao usuário
                await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Name);
                //fim da atribuição

                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                
                // Para obter mais informações sobre como habilitar a confirmação da conta e redefinição de senha, visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
                // Enviar um email com este link
                // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
                // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
                // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmar sua conta", "Confirme sua conta clicando <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">aqui</a>");

                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // Se chegamos até aqui e houver alguma falha, exiba novamente o formulário
        return View(model);
    }
```

E a minha View Account/Register:

```
   @model CadastroUsuariosProdutos.Models.RegisterViewModel

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Registre-se";
     }

   <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
  {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <h4>Crie uma nova conta.</h4>
   <hr />
   @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" 
  })
   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Selecionar o Tipo de Perfil para o usuário -->
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Selecione o Tipo de Perfil do Usuário", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Name")
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim da seleção do tipo de usuário -->

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Registrar-se" />
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Você está passando a lista de Nomes, que são seus roles através da `ViewBag.Name`

```
// GET: /Account/Register
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
    return View();
}
```

Porém em sua View você está tentando montar o DropDown partindo da propriedade `Name` da sua `RegisterViewModel`

```
<!-- Selecionar o Tipo de Perfil para o usuário -->
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Selecione o Tipo de Perfil do Usuário", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Name")
    </div>
</div>
```

Para que funcione corretamente você precisa popular esse dropdown pela ViewBag

```
@Html.DropDownList("Name", ViewBag.Name)
```

Comment: Olá Leandro.
Então essa linha com a ViewBag.Name não compila.
Na verdade a dropDown está sendo populado corretamente, porém é quando vai se registrar um novo usuário que acontece isso. O Get está funcionando.Vou colocar o RegisterViewModel.

Comment: public class RegisterViewModel
    {
        [Display(Name = "Nome")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        [Display(Name = "Email")]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O/A {0} deve ter no mínimo {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Senha")]

Comment: Tinha um parentese a mais, você tentou remover?

Comment: Sim, eu havia reparado. Não compilou.