# Converter uma String em IEnumerable<SelectListItem> em ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-identity

Me deparei com um erro de tipagem ao realizar um registro de um novo usuário. O projeto foi feito com a própria autenticidade do VS. Fiz a parte das Roles, que estão funcionando muito bem, o problema é quando registra um novo usuário com a role já cadastrada.

O erro é gerado na linha `@Html.DropDownList("Name")` da `View Register` ao tentar cadastrar o novo usuário.

O erro é esse:

> O item ViewData que possui a chave 'Name' é do tipo 'System.String',
> mas precisa ser do tipo 'IEnumerable'.

Acredito que eu precise enviar para a minha `View` uma `ViewBag` já do tipo `IEnumerable` ou retornar um tipo `IEnumerable` da `View`. Já tentei utilizar `.asEnumerable()` na classe do controller e não deu certo.

Meu `RegisterViewModel` que fica dentro do `AccountViewModel`:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Display(Name = "Nome")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "O/A {0} deve ter no mínimo 
    {2} caracteres.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Senha")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Confirmar Senha")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "A senha e a senha de 
    confirmação não correspondem.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

Meu Controller (`GET` e `POST`) que fica dentro do `AccountController`:

```
// GET: /Account/Register
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Register()
    {
        ViewBag.Name = new SelectList(context.Roles.ToList(), "Name", "Name");
        return View();
    }

//
// POST: /Account/Register
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
        var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            //Atribui o Peril ao usuário
            await this.UserManager.AddToRoleAsync(user.Id, model.Name);
            //fim da atribuição

            await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
            
            // Para obter mais informações sobre como habilitar a confirmação da conta e redefinição de senha, visite https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320771
            // Enviar um email com este link
            // string code = await UserManager.GenerateEmailConfirmationTokenAsync(user.Id);
            // var callbackUrl = Url.Action("ConfirmEmail", "Account", new { userId = user.Id, code = code }, protocol: Request.Url.Scheme);
            // await UserManager.SendEmailAsync(user.Id, "Confirmar sua conta", "Confirme sua conta clicando <a href=\"" + callbackUrl + "\">aqui</a>");

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        AddErrors(result);
    }

    // Se chegamos até aqui e houver alguma falha, exiba novamente o formulário
    return View(model);
```

E a minha View `Account/Register`:

```
@model CadastroUsuariosProdutos.Models.RegisterViewModel

    @{
       ViewBag.Title = "Registre-se";
     }

   <h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>

   @using (Html.BeginForm("Register", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
  {
   @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
   <h4>Crie uma nova conta.</h4>
   <hr />
   @Html.ValidationSummary("", new { @class = "text-danger" 
  })
   <div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.Password, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.ConfirmPassword, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>

<!-- Selecionar o Tipo de Perfil para o usuário -->
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.Label("Selecione o Tipo de Perfil do Usuário", new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownList("Name")
    </div>
</div>
<!-- Fim da seleção do tipo de usuário -->

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Registrar-se" />
    </div>
</div>
}

@section Scripts {
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: não é a mesma pergunta já aberta? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/496436/o-item-viewdata-que-possui-a-chave-name-%c3%a9-do-tipo-system-string-mas-precisa

Comment: Isto responde à sua pergunta? [O item ViewData que possui a chave 'Name' é do tipo 'System.String', mas precisa ser do tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>'](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/496436/o-item-viewdata-que-possui-a-chave-name-%c3%a9-do-tipo-system-string-mas-precisa)